# How to replace whitespace by dot in a column of names?

Tags: r, replace

Here I have a column of names where the First and Last names are deliminated by a whitespace, how can I convert it to dot deliminated? Like: Wayne.Ribbon, Rio.Mansey...

```
df <- data.frame (name  = c("Wayne Ribbon", "Rio Mansey", "Alexandre Trakovski"),
                  age = c(38,54,29))
```

Comment: in base R, `gsub` will do the trick

Comment: What have you tried? you added 4 tags ```loops```, ```for-loop```, ```dplyr``` and ```tidyverse``` without explaining if you tried those or if you want the answer to be in a loop or a tidy way. Please eleborate your quesion.

Comment: I tried dplyr, so I prefer it

Comment: what I meant was, which code have you tried to solve your question, what research have you done on stackoverflow, and what kind of errors/problems did you come across?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
the comment of @I_O should make it possible for you to solve your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the whitespace by a period using `sub`(if you always have one first name and one family name; if there are more than two parts, use `gsub`):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(name = sub(" ", ".", name))

#                  name age
# 1        Wayne.Ribbon  38
# 2          Rio.Mansey  54
# 3 Alexandre.Trakovski  29
```